# Reading OID and display its variable or name in python using pysnmp

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp, mib, oid

I am trying to write a code in python to run a function that reads the OID variable and name of a device.
I managed to find out their OID's but every time I enter the OID number in my code it shows me there is no OID

here is the Python code using pysnmp:

#########################

from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen

cmd_gen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

error_indication, error_status, error_index, var_binds = cmd_gen.getCmd(

```
    cmdgen.CommunityData('public'),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('192.168.178.213', 161)),

    '.1.3.6.1.4.1.9986.3.22.1.1.3.1.10')
```

for name, val in var_binds:

```
    print('%s' % val.prettyPrint())
```

#################

here is the device with one of the OIDs
[image]

Comment: https://community.helpsystems.com/knowledge-base/intermapper/snmp/querying-mib-variables/ Very basic knowledge on scalar and tabular can answer this question.

Comment: How can I use snmpwalk in my python code

I just want to print out the OID value

snmpwalk -v2c -c <our_community_string> <device_ip_address> 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.42.1.2.10.1.1.950

Comment: To query a table, you should WALK on a table OID or an entry OID. `1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.42.1.2.10.1.1.950` is not a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way of traversing OIDs in SNMP called SNMP WALK. It can be implemented as simple as this:

```
def walk_mib(ipaddress, oid):
    for (errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
               CommunityData('public'),
               UdpTransportTarget((ipaddress, 161)),
               ContextData(),
               ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid)),
               ):

        if not errorIndication and not errorStatus:
            for varBind in varBinds:
                result=' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind])
                print(result)


walk_mib('<ip address>', start_oid)
```